# Vista - Can I save different monitor configuration per user account?

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, user-accounts

I've got a two monitor setup for working on my computer, but would prefer to have just a single monitor active for family use on one particular user account.  Is there a way to have Vista remember different configurations for different user accounts?

Answer (score 2):

Use [UltraMon's Display Profiles](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/display_profiles.asp):

> Display profiles make it easy to
>   switch between different desktop
>   configurations. A profile stores the
>   display mode, position and state
>   (enabled/disabled) of each monitor, as
>   well as which monitor is primary
>   (changing the primary is only
>   supported on Windows 2000/XP and
>   later).
>
> **If your computer is used by more than
>   one person, you can use display
>   profiles to set up custom display
>   configurations for each user. Whenever
>   a user logs in, his or her display
>   settings will be applied.** Windows XP
>   Fast User Switching is supported.

Answer (score 0):

This program : ["XP Keep per User Display Settings"](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sto41/en/My%20Tools/XPKeepPerUserDisplaySettings.htm) is [reported](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-account-administration/75434-dpi-setting-not-user-specific.html) to also work in Vista.
I quote:

> The program is launched for each and
>   every user -- don't worry, it's rather
>   small -- and monitors the following
>   events:
>
> - switching among active users
> - users logging off
>
> Each time such an event occurs the
>   current user's display settings are
>   saved in that user's part of the
>   registry.
>   Conversely, each time a user logs in
>   or becomes active, his/her saved
>   settings are restored.